# Save an plot to an image, then draw additional lines on plot and save again.

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to draw a stripchart in R, save it to png file, then draw some more stuff on it and save it again. My attempts so far ended in an error `plot.new has not been called yet`. The corresponding code is

```
  # Draw without lines
  png(c(name, '.png'), width=480, height=240);
  stripchart(data, pch=4, method='jitter');
  dev.off();

  # Draw with with lines
  png(c(name, '_with_trim_points', '.png'), width=480, height=240);
  abline(v=points, untf = FALSE, col='red');
  abline(v=more__points, untf = FALSE, col='green')
  dev.off();
```

Just calling `stripchart(data, pch=4, method='jitter');` a second time is not an option, since the jitter will be different and end up with a different scatterplot.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (including the data)? Makes tinkering with code easier.

Comment: Have a look at `dev.copy()` there are some examples at the end which might help.

Comment: Or - as the jitters are generated randomly - set a seed, and reset it before making the new plot.

Comment: and - as an aside - you should use `paste0` to generate your filename. Not `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a seed and generated data

```
#generate data
data=data.frame(x=rnorm(40),y=rnorm(40))
points=c(-2,0)
more__points=c(1,2)



# Draw without lines
set.seed(123)
png(paste0(name, '.png'), width=480, height=240);
stripchart(data, pch=4, method='jitter');
dev.off();

# Draw with with lines
set.seed(123)
png(paste0(name, '_with_trim_points', '.png'), width=480, height=240);
stripchart(data, pch=4, method='jitter');
abline(v=points, untf = FALSE, col='red');
abline(v=more__points, untf = FALSE, col='green')
dev.off();
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can save your chart and also save it with 'saveRDS', then you can load it whenever your want and continue your work.